# Can I click on a word and it auto highlight the word?

Tags: vim

I see this intriguing feature in Notepad++.

For the same in vim I need to:

- click on a word
- press <kbd>*</kbd>

If I'd like to check different words, I need to press <kbd>*</kbd> many times. 
And it will automatically move my cursor to next matching word, which is not I want.

Can this be done like auto-highlighting and don't move my cursor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found how to do it: add following into `.vimrc`

```
autocmd CursorMoved * silent! exe printf('match Search /\<%s\>/', expand('<cword>'))
autocmd CursorHold *  silent! exe printf('match Search /\<%s\>/', expand('<cword>'))
```

And you can also replace the `Search` above with whatever `highlight` you like, even self-defined scheme.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few short scripts on [this page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_all_search_pattern_matches).